# Optaplanner - availability of Vehicles

Tags: optaplanner

I am working on a VRPTW problem where vehicles have availablity constraints. This means that they might not be available the entire period of a day - basically a time windows for vehicles. Is there a way to build this in optaplanner?

Thank you and Brgds,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following should work:

- add 2 fields (start and end) on `(TimeWindowed)Vehicle`
- in `ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener` use at least the vehicle's start time before it leaves a depot
- add a hard constraint that the vehicle should be back at the depot by it's end time. Make sure to penalize not just -1, but instead, minus the amount of time it's overdue (to avoid a score trap, see docs).

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey! - Excellent support from your side!