# OptaPlanner Vehicle Routing - Time Window for vehicles

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

First of all, thanks to the ones who are invoved on this great library.

My constraints are:

- I have customers which have ready and due times.
- And vehicles which also have ready and due times.

I am not experienced in Java and I try to use OptaPlanner by sending and recieving xml using the example project provided. For the customers time window, I have used "VrmTimeWindowedCustomer" and there was no problem with that. And for the vehicles time window constraint, I tried to use "VrpTimeWindowedDepot"

What was in my mind is: When a depot is available (ReadyTime) the vehicle start to work from that depot and go to the customers. However in my tries OptaPlanner did not gave the results I was expecting:

```
<depotList id="139">
    <VrpTimeWindowedDepot id="140">
      <id>1</id>
      <location class="VrpRoadLocation" reference="3"/>
      <readyTime>540000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1020000</dueTime>
    </VrpTimeWindowedDepot>
    <VrpTimeWindowedDepot id="141">
      <id>2</id>
      <location class="VrpRoadLocation" reference="5"/>
      <readyTime>540000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1020000</dueTime>
    </VrpTimeWindowedDepot>
  </depotList>
```

Result is:

```
<VrpVehicle id="143">
      <id>1</id>
      <capacity>100001002</capacity>
      <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="140"/>
      <nextCustomer class="VrpTimeWindowedCustomer" id="144">
        <id>42</id>
        <location class="VrpRoadLocation" reference="85"/>
        <demand>206</demand>
        <previousStandstill class="VrpVehicle" reference="143"/>
        <nextCustomer class="VrpTimeWindowedCustomer" id="146">
           ...
        <vehicle reference="143"/>
        <readyTime>0</readyTime>
        <dueTime>1440000</dueTime>
        <serviceDuration>12000</serviceDuration>
        <arrivalTime>22137</arrivalTime>
      </nextCustomer>
      <vehicle reference="143"/>
      <readyTime>0</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1440000</dueTime>
      <serviceDuration>12000</serviceDuration>
      <arrivalTime>8527</arrivalTime>
    </nextCustomer>
  </VrpVehicle>
```

ArrivalTime on the customers are OK for the customers, but smaller than the Depot ReadyTime of that vehicle.

I couldn't find out what am I doing wrong here. 
I have read [Optaplanner - availability of Vehicles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307115/optaplanner-availability-of-vehicles) and OptaPlanner documents; but could not understand and figure out what to do for my situation.

I also couldn't understand the syntax of a drl file and couldn't find a document that explains how to write it.

**Edit - Another Question to Geoffrey De Smet**

Geoffrey De Smet, thank you very much for your fast respose, it is very appreciated. I have tried your changes. The arrival times are now OK according to the Depot's ReadyTime. However there might be another problem about the Depot's DueTime:

```
   <VrpTimeWindowedDepot id="144">
      <id>3</id>
      <location class="VrpRoadLocation" reference="7"/>
      <readyTime>540000</readyTime>
      <dueTime>1020000</dueTime>
    </VrpTimeWindowedDepot>
```

The last customer to be visited for a vehicle from this depot is:

```
<nextCustomer class="VrpTimeWindowedCustomer" id="183">
  <id>36</id>
  <location class="VrpRoadLocation" reference="73"/>
  <demand>187</demand>
  <previousStandstill class="VrpTimeWindowedCustomer" reference="182"/>
  <vehicle reference="146"/>
  <readyTime>0</readyTime>
  <dueTime>1440000</dueTime>
  <serviceDuration>10000</serviceDuration>
  <arrivalTime>1082091</arrivalTime>
</nextCustomer>
```

Shouldn't the arrival time be less than 1020000? (There are 3 vehicles on 3 depots. In the solution only 2 vehicles were involved, both having such finish times.)

I have tried to add this as a comment to the PLANNER-680 JIRA issue, but I was unable to sing up and login. I hope the this edit is ok according to the Stackoverflow's format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember doing a hack in the example related to due time of a vehicle/depot in the txt importer ([see this line](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/persistence/VehicleRoutingImporter.java#L513)). That hasn't been cleaned up yet, so the XML can punch through it. But that's not your issue here.

It seems like there is a bug on this line in ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener:

```
    protected void updateArrivalTime(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, TimeWindowedCustomer sourceCustomer) {
        Standstill previousStandstill = sourceCustomer.getPreviousStandstill();
        Long departureTime = (previousStandstill instanceof TimeWindowedCustomer)
? ((TimeWindowedCustomer) previousStandstill).getDepartureTime() : null;
```

that doesn't take `vehicle.getDepot().getReadyTime()` into account.

Comment: Wow thats fast :) Can you add the bug fixed code; or is there any way that I can reach the 7.0.0.Beta3 files?

Comment: See link in jira issue.